# в шаблоне ошибка wrong number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

есть следующий action в контролере

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
 def index
   @appointment = Appointment.new
   @appointments = Appointment.order('app_time ASC')
 end
end
```

и вьюха

```
= form_with @appointment  do |f|
  = f.text_field :title
  = f.text_field :app_time
  = f.submit 'Make appointment'
```

но при рендере вьюхи выходит ошибка 
[image: ошибка]

Comment: Изучите внимательно, пожалуйста: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with

Comment: Вы, видимо, привыкли к старому `form_for`, возможно прочитали о нём в старых материалах и решили, что это то же самое. Отвыкайте :)

Answer (score 3):

Хелпер form_with требует параметров в виде keyword_arguments:

```
form_with(model: nil, scope: nil, url: nil, format: nil, **options)
```

В вашем случае:

```
= form_with model: @appointment  do |f|
```